# issue while mimicking graphQL request in postman using devtools's payload

Tags: graphql, postman

> I am trying to hit GraphQL Api in Postman using payload I got in chrome's devtools. There are two variables page and `selfdefinedfilter`. But in devtools's payload section only page variable is defined. I am not getting this `selfdefinedfilter` value in anywhere in devtools. I am trying to mimic same request using postman. So there it is giving me error. Any idea related where to find this variable value.

There is one variable used in query but haven't defined in variables field.
Actual Payload:

```
{
  "operationName": "ingress",
  "variables": {
    "page": {
      "first": 100,
      "page": 1
    }
  },
  "query": "query ingress($filter:selfdefinedfilter , $page: page) {
  ingress(filter: $filter, page: $page) {someFields  } }
  "

}
```

I have checked previous request also whether anything is getting set for this. But I got nothing. Also Checked for cache, memory storage where it might get its value.

Answer (score 0):

`seldefinedfilter` is not a required variable. In the cases you have observed it is simply not being set. You're going to have to observe more requests to try to find one where it is actually used to infer it's shape and properties.